# OleDbDataAdapter Powershell Connecting to Sharepoint List

Tags: powershell

I have a situation where I can retrieve results using this query

```
Select * From myList (myList being Sharepoint list)
```

but cannot get results from this

```
select First From myList Where First=JoeBob
```

No insert query works either.

```
$connString = 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=2;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=https://sharepoint/;LIST={897BJ54-AAAA-4989-BH56-8JFJS758BN};'
$spConn = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($connString)
$spConn.open()
write-host $spConn.State
$qry='SELECT * FROM myList'
$cmd = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($qry,$spConn)
$da = new-object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($cmd)
$dt = new-object System.Data.dataTable
$da.fill($dt)
$dt
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

I've done some Powershell scripting with OleDB and SharePoint and blog about it here:
http://sev17.com/2009/02/using-oledb-with-sharepoint-lists/

It looks like you are missing single quotes around JoeBob:

"select First From myList Where ='JoeBob'"

As noted in my blog post inserts statements are not supported.